# VSCode: set terminal shell on workspaces after latest update

Tags: visual-studio-code

On VSCode, if I needed a different terminal shell on a certain workspace, I had added the following setting in the workspace file (`.code-workspace`):

```
"settings": {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "path\to\the\shell.exe"
}
```

After the latest update (*April 2021 - version 1.56*) this doesn't work anymore and I get this warning:

> This is deprecated, use `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#` instead

If I replace the setting name with the suggested one I get:

> This setting can be applied only in application user settings

How can I set a different terminal shell per workspace?

Comment: Seems to be a known open issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121470

Comment: This issue is over as with the latest update version of vs code Version: 1.56.2, one really does not need to provide the explicit path to the terminal bin on the disk. I just deleted all the absolute path and after that by hitting ctrl + shift + p and type default terminal you can just choose which one you want to be default and that's it.

Comment: @CarlosPimentel I don't want to choose (and remember the right one) every time, I like to set the right terminal shell per workspace. Fortunately [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67434338/3236352) is still working

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, here is the same issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123031 from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123133.

Issue 123133 was closed 05/05/2021 with a temporary fix, see that issue and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/006591a7cfa31b9778e712b742b6e37f4afd0ed9.  Here is my Insiders Build workspace settings file after the fix:

[image: terminal default profile fix]

Note the previous error message is gone.  I suspect that this "fix" will be in a point release to v1.56 fairly soon rather than waiting for v1.57.

Answer (score 0):

As [zendu pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410502/vscode-set-terminal-shell-on-workspaces-after-latest-update?noredirect=1#comment119181777_67410502), there's an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121470) about it with a [temporary fix](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121470#issuecomment-828525577):

> A temporary fix was added to re-enable workspace shell settings when `"terminal.integrated.allowWorkspaceConfiguration": true` is set [#122104](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122104)

I tried it and it seems to work (at least for now).