# How to set a different default terminal for workspaces in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Prior to the VS Code April 2021 update, it was possible to set a default terminal in user settings, then override it in workspace settings for projects that needed a different terminal, like this:

User settings:

```js
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"
```

Workspace settings:

```js
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

Now that `terminal.integrated.shell` has been deprecated, how would these settings be migrated?

I can use the following in user settings to set WSL as default:

```js
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu (WSL)"
```

...but `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile` can't be set in workspace settings, so I can't use it to override the setting to a different terminal.

`terminal.integrated.automationShell` can be used in workspace settings to override the terminal that's used for automation (npm scripts, for instance), but not terminals that are launched manually.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410502/vscode-set-terminal-shell-on-workspaces-after-latest-update/67421814#67421814

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can use `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows"` in the workspace settings now to override your user settings.

(You can also override the `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"` list if you want to pass additional workspace-specific options to your terminal.)

Comment: This was so easy....like 3 clicks.  set it, and forget it.  Thanks!